# Necessary and sufficient conditions on eigenvalues so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x(t)=0$ where $x(t)$ is the solution of $\dot x = Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ have real and distinct eigenvalues. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t) =0 $ where $x(t) $ is solution of $\dot x  = Ax $?

Answer (score 0):

Sufficient is that all the eigenvalues are negative.

Really, the eigenvalues could all be positive!  Consider $A=\text{diag}(1,2,\cdots,n)$  and $x(0)=(0,0,\cdots,0)^T.$  So there are no necessary conditions on the eigenvalues alone.

If you want to understand better the dynamics, we can consider the 2-d case and generalize from there.  If both eigenvalues are negative so all solutions approach the origin and the origin is a "sink", or both are positive and the origin is a "source".  If we have one positive and one negative, we have a saddle point at the origin, and the initial condition must be along a trajectory going towards the origin.  We could also have one eigenvalue zero or both zero $\cdots.$

Comment: Negative eigenvalues will generate phase portraits that are stables and pointing towards the Origin of the space ( in 2D this would be the point (0,0)). If the eigenvalues are positive then it becomes unstable and move away from 0. So am I correct saying that the requirement is that they are both negative? I guess I do not understand your comment about the positive ones.

Comment: Negative eigenvalues are sufficient.  They are not necessary if you start at the origin, or along a path leading to the origin (in the mixed case).

Comment: So more generally the natural necessary and sufficient condition you're referencing is $\displaystyle x(0) \in \sum_{r < 0} E_r$ where $E_r$ is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $r$?